# Django how to see generated SQL query?

Tags: python, django

I have a form which takes data and is supposed to insert it into a database. When I am processing that form it gives me a value error, but when I go to the database and try to insert it manually it works fine.

In order to debug this situation, I want to see what query Django is generating which is failing. On the debug webpage I didn't see anything like SQL query.

How can I see the actual query generated by Django?

Please advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about using logging?

you can add this in settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

and you can add this in your any views.py

```
import logging

l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

In your console, you can check SQL query.

Another way

go shell

```
python manage.py shell

>>from yourmodel import Example
>>queryset = Example.objects.all()
>>print(queryset.query)
```

you can see raw query string.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to use PyCharm, running your application in the debugger gives you the full context. Set a breakpoint, and browse in your app to the point you are having the error and get a screen like (trivial example):
[image]

Running in this way has changed the way I troubleshoot when using Django. I suspect other IDE's may have similar features. Some further video documentation of the process from the vendor at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0

As Jayground suggested, logging is probably something you'll turn on eventually anyway; great suggestion.

Comment: Thanks AMG. I will try with pycharm as well and learn how to do it. Thanks for sharing this. Really appreciate this.

Answer (score 2):

According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

> connection.queries includes all SQL statements – INSERTs, UPDATES, SELECTs, etc. Each time your app hits the database, the query will be recorded.

So you can access these queries by running

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries)
```