# possible to filter the queryset after querying? django

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

Sorry if the question sounds weird.  I am just wondering if there is possible to make new queryset when I already have a queryset.

For example here...

```
 everyone = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)  # this would of course return all users that's active
 not_deleted = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_deleted=False)  # return user that's active and not deleted
 is_deleted = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_deleted=True)  # return user that's active and is already deleted
```

What my question is...for `not_deleted` and `is_deleted` they both have active is true with is the same as `everyone` is there a possible way to use `everyone` and then somehow filter out `is_deleted=True` or `is_deleted=False`?   So then I believe the querying would be faster and better if this is possible right?

All three variables `everyone`, `not_deleted` and `is_deleted` will then be used for something else.

Hopefully I made my question quiet clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44):

Yes, you can reuse existing querysets.

```
everyone = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
active_not_deleted = everyone.filter(is_deleted=False)
active_is_deleted = everyone.filter(is_deleted=True)
```

This is not really making anything faster though, in fact, this code block won't even execute a query against the database because Django QuerySets are lazily evaluated.  What I means is that it won't send the query to the database until you actually need the values.  Here's an example that will talk to the database.

```
everyone = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)  # Building SQL...
active_not_deleted = everyone.filter(is_deleted=False)  # Building SQL...
active_is_deleted = everyone.filter(is_deleted=True)  # Building SQL...

# Example of the whole queryset being evaluated
for user in everyone:
    # This will execute the query against the database to return the list of users
    # i.e. "select * from user where is_active is True;"
    print(user)

# Example of using iterator to evaluate one object at a time from the queryset.
for user in active_not_deleted.iterator():
    # This will execute the query for each result, so it doesn't
    # load everything at once and it doesn't cache the results.
    # "select * from user where is_active is True and is_deleted is False limit 1 offset 0;"
    # The offset is incremented on each loop and another query is sent to retrieve the next user in the list.
    print(user)
```

Recommend reading:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#iterator
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

As an addition to this answer, you could make a single query and then filter in Python if you really wanted.  Mind you, you could not do subsequent filtering on the lists because they are not QuerySets.

```
everyone = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
active_not_deleted = list(filter(lambda user: user.is_deleted is False), list(everyone))
active_is_deleted = list(filter(lambda user: user.is_deleted is True), list(everyone))
```

In this last example, `everyone` is a queryset, and `active_not_deleted` and `active_is_deleted` are Python lists of User objects.  The `everyone` queryset will only be evaluated once in the first `list(everyone)` call, and then the results are cached.

Comment: as I mentioned to `Jayground` so I guess there is no other way to hit the db less times and also have a better performance advantage right? for sure I would need all these query at one point that's why I created these queries.  I thought if there's a possible way to chain them, then there's possible way to hit the db less and have a better performance

Comment: I can't really think of a way to optimize these three queries into one.  The alternative would be make a single query against the User model, and then filter the results in python.

Comment: think you are able to provide a more detail example? (just to be honest, most likely I would give the check to `Jayground` though as he gave me a more detailed before you did)

Comment: @Dora I have actually added an example of filtering the QuerySet in python to reduce it to one query, there are caveats though which you should keep in mind.  I think the documentation I've linked is very important to understanding how Django QuerySets are behaving under the hood.

Answer (score 7):

## 1. chain filter method

```
not_deleted = User.objects.filter(active=True).filter(is_deleted=False)
```

@Cory Madden already answered. `User.objects.filter(active=True)` returns Queryset. So you can add filter method. `active_users.filter(is_deleted=False)`

## 2. using Q method

```
from django.db.models import Q

not_deleted = User.objects.filter(Q(active=True) & Q(is_deleted=False)
```

It is easier to manage your complicated queryset. What if you want to filter userID is not 3? you can use Q simplye like `User.objects.filter(Q(active=True) & ~Q(id = 3))`

---

Answer for your comment,

Using Q or not, it has same raw query.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... 
WHERE ("auth_user"."active" = True AND "auth_user"."is_deleted" = False)
```

Database performance is relating to how often you hit database to extract data or if you use a heavy method like 'Join' when you extract something by FK relationship. So Using Q or not doesn't give you performance difference, because it has same query sentence.

Additionally,

```
user = User.objects.filter(active=True)
not_deleted = User.objects.filter(active=True).filter(is_deleted=False)

user = User.objects.filter(active=True)
not_deleted = user.filter(is_deleted=False)
```

would not give you performance difference.

Queryset is lazy. `user` and `not_deleted` variables have just queryset string. It doesn't hit the database right away when you define variable like above. Anyway, you will hit three times for each variable.

Comment: which of these would you prefer and gives actual performance advantage though?  Also, is there something that I can calculate the loading time? Something equivalent to `console.time` in `js` ?

Comment: so to be in general, even if I stick with my script in the question, it would give the same performance as the answers provided by you or others because all of them would hit the db 3 times, there's no other option to hit the db only once and the other two depend on the first queryset variable right?

Comment: Well, if it is really important to hit database one time, you can use forloop and divide into two list. `for user in User.objects.filter(active=True):` 'if user.is_deleted==True: something like this. But I don't know if it will give you performance advantage because it also need your server side resource anyway. Or you can send data to browser and sorting this data with javascript on browser. This is what I can answer so far. additionally, you can check how to see raw query by logging with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41389728/6568309.

Answer (score 4):

The best you can do is:

```
active_users = User.objects.filter(active=True)
not_deleted = active_users.filter(is_deleted=False)
deleted = active_users.filter(is_deleted=True)
```

So the answer to your question may be yes, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: This will work, but it will not give any performance advantage over the original. It is possible to chain many of the `Queryset` returning methods and also store the in between value to a variable but the actual SQL query result in not stored since the query is only executed when a method is called that does not return a `Queryset`.

Comment: @KlausD. is there a possible way to have a performance advance though?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter Queryset so much time that you want, because `filter()` returns a new Queryset so after filtering you get filtered Queryset and you can do filter or orderby and another [methods that return new QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets)

So you can do this:

```
active = User.objects.filter(active=True)
deleted = active.filter(is_deleted=True)
not_deleted = active.filter(is_deleted=False)
```

All it is because `User.objects` - is Queryset and `User.objects.filter` also return Queryset.