# Load All Data in Table from Django Models run queries from it

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to know how can we run queries from data after loading entirely in Memory to prevent it from hitting database everytime

This is my Model

```
class empdb(models.Model):
    empid   = models.CharField(max_length=8,primary_key=True)
    empname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    empdept = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('empid',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.empid
```

This is what I am trying

```
record = empdb.objects.all()   ' This will load all data in "record"
```

Now How to read from it and extract Data based on our Query

I am trying below query to find out which Employees are part of HR Department

```
   dataset=backuprecord.filter(empdept='HR')
   print(dataset)
```

Now this is where I am getting stuck. The Output I get is fine and it does list the Data I get , but its in below form

```
<QuerySet [<empid: 10010>,<empid: 10121>,<empid: 12235>,<empid: 18110>]>
```

I want to takeout the empid and empname from above queryset

How do I do so ?

What I want is data in below variables

```
for i  in <length of query set> 
    foundempid[i] =  ''' The Employee ID from the queryset Line 
    foundempname[i] = ''' The Employee Name
```

Any Help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess you this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45229042/5022847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataset=backuprecord.filter(empdept='HR')
```

In `dataset`, you will be getting [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/). Django makes DB query and use ORM to convert it to Model instances. Collection of instances is called a queryset. Now, when you want to get a model instance(ORM for a single row from the table), the you can do it [many ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets). Here, if you want to access all the objects in `dataset`, you can simply loop through it, and like every objects, you can get the value via `<object>.attribute_name`. For example:

```
dataset=backuprecord.filter(empdept='HR')

for data in dataset:
   print(data.emdid)
   print(data.empname)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `values` function like this.

```
empdb.objects.filter(your_filter_params).values('empid', 'empname')
```

this will give you list of dictionaries.

> [{'empid': 1212, 'empname': 'Name'}, {'empid': 1212, 'empname': 'Name'}]

You can get this in list form like this.

```
empids = empdb.objects.filter(your_filter_params).values_list('empid', flat=True)
empnames = empdb.objects.filter(your_filter_params).values_list('empname', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset=empdb.objects.filter(empdept='HR').values('empdid','empname')
for data in dataset:
    print data['empdid'], data['empname']
```

I suggest you to start a class name with Uppercase letters as it is the standard way to do. For example give class name as `class Empdb`

Answer (score 0):

`.all()` is redudant here `record = empdb.objects.all()`  you can directly do `empdb.objects.filter(empdept='HR')` you dont need to fetch all here then query

`empdb.objects.filter(empdept="HR").values('empid)` to get your required  values or `values()` to get all data in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you do it.

```
dataset= empdb.objects.filter(empdept='HR').value_list('empid','empname')

zipped_data = zip(range(len(dataset)),dataset) #python 2.7
zipped_data = list(zip(range(len(dataset)),dataset)) #python 3.6

for i, data  in zipped_data: 
    foundempid[i] =  data[0] The Employee ID from the queryset Line 
    foundempname[i] = data[1] The Employee Name
```

Please let me know if you facing any issues.